# Por que usar o Docker no Azure?

Tags: arquitetura-de-software, microsoft-azure, cloud, docker

Esse ano eu vi que o Azure disponibilizou um serviço de containers chamado "Azure Container Service". Esse serviço, entre outras coisas, permite utilizar o Docker no Azure.

Acontece que o Docker é um sistema de containers. Pelo que eu entendi sobre ele até agora, sua principal vantagem é não precisar de virtualização. Ele permite conseguir um isolamento sem necessitar de virtualização e sem precisar de um sistema operacional inteiro. Na verdade ele só precisa do user space, porque o Kernel ele usa o mesmo do Host.

Por outro lado, o Azure é baseado em máquinas virtuais. Tudo que se executa no Azure está sendo executado em uma máquina virtual. Nesse sentido, se usarmos o Docker no Azure, vamos estar usando um container dentro de uma máquina virtual.

Mas novamente, por que alguem faria isso, se o container existe justamente para evitar as máquinas virtuais? Quais as vantagens e motivos para usar o Docker no Azure?

Comment: Esta pergunta tem 3 votos de fechamento como principalmente baseada em opiniões. Entretanto, me parece ser uma pergunta válida e perfeitamente respondível sem necessitar-se de pontos de vista. Uma pergunta do tipo "*Quais as vantagens e motivos para usar o Docker no Azure?*" é tão válida quanto uma "*Quais as vantagens e motivos para usar programação orientada a objetos?*" - ambas podem ser respondidas de forma objetiva e imparcial embasada apenas em aspectos técnicos. Alguém que defende o fechamento gostaria de argumentar?

Answer (score 3):

Vou tentar responder todas as dúvidas. Se algo não ficou claro, basta comentar que vou complementando a resposta, combinado?

O Azure é um provider de nuvem. Nele encontramos dois tipo de serviços que podemos consumir:

- IaaS - Infrastruture as a Service: Onde, sim, é um ambiente totalmente gerenciável para virtualização de infraestrutura, ou seja, máquinas virtuais, redes, armazenamentos, etc.
- PaaS - Platform as a Service: Onde podemos consumir plataformas prontas. Neste caso não há virtualização - ao menos não diretamente. Neste caso consumimos recursos prontos para uso como bancos de dados, sistemas de busca e, principalmente, hospedagem de aplicações.

[Azure Container Service](https://azure.microsoft.com/pt-br/services/container-service/) é um PaaS. Quando se aloca esse tipo de serviço, não é colocado à você uma VM à sua disposição para ser configurada/customizada. Ele já vem pronto e configurado apenas para seu consumo.

Então, quando usamos, por exemplo, o PaaS Azure WebApps, para hospedagem de aplicações web, não estão necessariamente subindo uma VM para alocar sua aplicação. O servidor físico de hospedagem de aplicações já está lá, dentro do datacenter, você apenas irá hospedar seu app nele, e reservar recursos - cpu, ram. E acontece o mesmo com o Azure Container Service. Voce pede para provisionar o serviço para ti, e depois basta consumilo, te isentando da responsabilidade de manter servidores.

Sobre as vantagens de usar Azure Container Service, ou qualquer outro PaaS no Azure:

- Voce fica isento de resposabilidade pela manutenção da infraestrutura;
- Será cobrado apenas pelos recursos utilizados, nada mais;
- Já conta com demais serviços pertinentes e agregados como backup, DR, redundancia, etc;
- Fácil de escalar, verticalmente e horizontalmente;
- O serviço já conta com inúmeras métricas de consumo de recursos;

Então, pode ficar tranquilo, pois o serviço de container do Azure é uma plataforma, basta provisionar e consumir.

Answer (score 2):

Independente do provider, densidade computacional é algo almejado. Não é otimizado, ou melhorado, por questões de segurança. Com o isolamento thin oquestrado pelo docker, é possível aumentar a densidade computacional, utilizando menos recursos, já que você pode substituir diversas VM's por containers em um só host, ou em vez de ter uma super máquina, distribuir elasticamente entre máquinas menores, agora, desligáveis.